# Meteor each placeholder for deleting specific document

Tags: mongodb, session, meteor, each, spacebars

How would I have a session variable in a spacebars {{#each}} for a document that was just removed? I would like to notify the user that they have just removed something and the message would be in place of the same document.

For example:

```
{{#each list}}
   <span>{{number}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

Would compile to:

```
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
```

If I were to remove the 2nd document {number: 2} from the collection then the template would react accordingly to the change as expected:

```
<span>1</span>
<span>3</span>
```

Instead, I want it to display the following instead after the Mongo remove statement:

```
<span>1</span>
<span>You have deleted 2</span>
<span>3</span>
```

Comment: A flash message (temporary), or permanent in the correct position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using _uihooks to insert a placeholder element each time element is deleted. I created a [meteor pad with an example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/CXyvMLSiD3MMv34PR/Item%20placeholder).

client.js

```
Template.body.events({
  "click #add-item": function() {
    Items.insert({name: "Item"});
  },
  "click .delete": function() {
    Items.remove({_id: this._id});
  }
});

Template.body.helpers({
  items: function() {
    return Items.find({});
  }
});

Template.body.rendered = function() {
  Meteor.defer(function(){
    document.getElementById("items")._uihooks = {
      removeElement: function(node) {
        var placeholder = document.createElement("li");
        $(placeholder).html("Placeholder");
        $(placeholder).insertBefore(node);
        $(node).remove();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

main.html

```
<body>
<ul id="items">
{{#each items}}
  <li>
    {{name}}
    <button class="delete">delete</button>
  </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
<button id="add-item">Add item</button>
</body>
```